# algorithm to convert decimal to fraction expression

Tags: c, haskell

supposing I have a decimal like

```
0.30000000000000027
```

What would be the best algorithm to know the same number expressed as a fraction 
So given certain `x` find `y` that satisfies `x=1/y` in c or haskell

I was thinking

```
 1/3> 0.30 >1/4
```

Iterating left and right side til one of them converges and `>` becomes `=` 
so first iteration would look like

```
1/1  >  0.30000000000000027  > 1/somethinghere
1/2  >  0.30000000000000027  > 1/increase or decrease this 
1/3  >  0.30000000000000027 ...
```

I want to clarify that I could easily do

```
0.30000000000000027  =  30000000000000027/  10^17
```

but I want to do

```
0.30000000000000027 = 1/x
```

In c or haskell

Comment: Not all numbers can be thus expressed, for example, 0.8 = 4/5.

Comment: yes got it but if algorithm does not converge, then I have a number with this quality

Comment: Then you just want a fraction simplification algorithm, see, i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777142/how-to-simplify-a-fraction.

Comment: Every fraction will be between `1/n` and `1/(n+1)`, so just iterate until you find such a pair.

Comment: @Koterpillar No, that assumes he already has a fraction. He's trying to find the fraction in the first place.

Comment: why dont you do `y = 1.0/x'? i.e `1.0/0.30000whatever` will give the number?

Comment: @Barmar, you can start with `30000000000000027/10^17`.

Comment: @Koushik 1.0/0.30000whatever = 3.333333333333333 so....

Comment: you want a proper fraction?

Comment: yeah if possible like x = 1/y

Comment: @cMinor, what answer do you want for 0.3? 0.8?

Comment: well, I was even thinking that adding a imaginary number or something like that may solve the issue on those cases, maybe I am wrong

Comment: Imaginary numbers solve problems with roots, they have nothing to do with multiplication and division.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Algorithm for simplifying decimal to fractions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124743/algorithm-for-simplifying-decimal-to-fractions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction)? They give very good approximations of numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Voila (converts almost properly to a normal fraction):

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0) return b;
    if (b == 0) return a;

    if (a > b)
        return gcd(b, a % b);
    else
        return gcd(a, b % a);
}

struct frac {
    int num;
    int denom;
};

struct frac to_frac(double x, int precision)
{
    int denom = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < precision; i++) {
        denom *= 10;
    }

    int num = x * denom + 0.5; // hack: round if imprecise
    int gcdiv = gcd(num, denom);

    struct frac f;
    f.num = num / gcdiv;
    f.denom = denom / gcdiv;

    return f;
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: this is not production-ready, some refining is needed if you want it to work in all circumstances - that's left as an exercise, this much code should be enough to get OP started.

Comment: He wants his numerator always to be 1. His statement about possibly using imaginary numbers shows how confused he is about math.

Comment: @Barmar ... (but you **can't express any fraction with a numerator of 1!**)

Comment: @Barmar Still, you're right, but what he wants is impossible, I'm not even sure that's exactly what he wants. This is the closest answer I can imagine that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know haskell, here it is in pseudo-code:

```
raw_denom = 1/x;
print "1/" floor(raw_denom) " >= " x " >= 1/" ceil(raw_denom)
```

Comment: `1/1 >= 0.8 >= 1/2` IT all depends on the (ill defined) design requirements, but that meets some interpretation.  In Haskell: `func x = let raw_denom = 1/x in putStrLn $ "1/" ++ show (floor raw_denom) ++ " >= " ++ show x ++ " >= 1/" ++ show (ceiling raw_denom)`

Comment: My answer prints what he wrote after "I was thinking" in his question.