# Get the ratio (x:y) between two numbers

Tags: node.js

I am looking to get the ratio (example 1:3) between two numbers.

I have two numbers joins, and leaves. I would like to get the ratio between these numbers in a way that would return "for every x joins y leaves"

Comment: Can't you just divide one number by the other and display that factor? This is more of a basic math question than a programming question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simplify a fraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777142/how-to-simplify-a-fraction)

Comment: this is just a greatest common divisor question